# Bootstrap 4, in a input date smaller text is not visible

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a very high form with lot of input fields, so I had to reduce the height of every input.
As also bootstrap form-control-sm was not tight enough for me, I created a new class form-control-xs:

```
.form-control-xs {
    height: 20px!important;
    padding: .025rem .25rem !important;
    font-size: .75rem !important;
    line-height: 0;
    border-radius: .2rem;
}
```

Everything is working well, except the "date" input fields, as you see in the image the text is not visible.
It seems like there is an inner margin or padding, but i don't understand how to change it.
Do you know if is it possible to do it?

[image]

I add a snippet:

```css
.form-control-xs {
    height: 20px!important;
    padding: .025rem .25rem !important;
    font-size: .75rem !important;
    line-height: 0;
    border-radius: .2rem;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                        <label for="from" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">LABEL</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-7 ">
                            <input type="date" class="form-control form-control-xs" stl NAME="from"  autocomplete="off" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </fieldset>
```

Comment: I can't at the moment reproduce your problem using a simple test. Please could you put a snippet of code into your question that demonstrates the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I edited the question with a snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.form-control-xs {
    height: 20px!important;
    font-size: .75rem !important;
    border-radius: .2rem;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                        <label for="from" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">LABEL</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-7 ">
                            <input type="date" class="form-control form-control-xs" stl NAME="from"  autocomplete="off" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </fieldset>
```

Comment: easier than expected... thank you very much!